# Monitor keep goes ON and STANDBY while screen turned OFF

Tags: display, multiple-monitors

On my 2 monitors configuration (Windows 10) my primary monitor goes ON and STANDBY all the time (for example over the night) while screen is turned OFF in Windows. To prevent this I manually turn off monitors.
How can I stop this because I'm afraid this will cause monitor malfunction after some time.
Both monitors are connected to DP.

When Windows send PC to SLEEP then both monitors are stable in standby mode.

Comment: Hello, did You find a solution to this issue? I have the same problem and cannot find a reason.

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer- 1. Check monitor input type and settings 2. Power supply is playing hide and seek with monitor.

Long Answer.
I am assuming your monitor is connected via HDMI cable. Monitor are supposed to look for active signal transmitting source. If you have more that one input type then the monitor keeps switching between modes like HDMI, DVI, VGA in search of active signal especially it the input signal is set to Auto. I have observed in past that Monitors with single input type do not behave like you described. It would be also worth to check if there are any default ON/OFF time settings in your monitor's menu.

Your power supply also adds to this problem. Many power-supply behave differently in Sleep vs Hibernate mode. A Watt meter hooked to power-supply (monitor power is not connected to meter) shows few watts consumed in SLEEP mode while zero power Hibernate. This behavior is not consistent across power supply manufactures or even models therein. Some power-supply keep activating the motherboard intermittently not enough to start the system but enough to power-up the display port which in turn interpreted by monitor as wake signal. Your graphic card may or may not do anything in this situation but on-board graphics will most likely cause monitor to wake-up.

My advice: Don't worry about monitor going bad. Nowadays monitors come with huge on/off duty cycle to last a lifetime.

On a lighter note - This possessed monitor can spook kids and some adults too at night. Better to power off monitor at night. go green.

NOTE - Hi fellow Quora users. I am new to Quora and find this platform very informative and want to contribute based on my real life experience. So I kindly ask you to up-vote so that I can get basic reputation for voting rights. Thanks

Comment: Both monitors are connected to DP.

Comment: Sorry, I made wrong description. The problem is turned off screen in windows. I corrected description now. Your answer helped me to discover this.